# JavaFX некорректный вывод X-Bee пакета в файл

Tags: java, javafx

Имеется строковая переменная

```
public static String MSG;
```

Её задача получить пакет данных от сети X-Bee и вывести на экран приложения и записать в текст.

```
MSG = new String(xBeePacket.toString());
helloWorld2.appendText("IN: "+MSG+"\n"); //запись в текстовое поле helloWorld2

    try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(filename(), true)) 
    {            
                 writer.append(MSG);            
                 writer.append("\r\n");
                 writer.flush();
             }  
    catch (IOException ex) { System.out.println(ex.getMessage());     }
```

В текстовое поле всё приходит четко. Например пришло 2 пакета:
7E0023910013A200414F926F68FEE8E80011C1050101FCA0550153158E07134650019047505306
7E0023910013A200415B69C75C5AE8E80011C1050101FCA0550153158E0713465001904750537B

А вот в файле это выглядит иначе:
7E0023910013A200414F926F68FEE8E80011C1050101FCA0550153158E07134650019047505306
��US�FP�GPS

Можно заметить, что в конце есть символы GPS, однако в пакете еоды этих символов не последние, выходит, что он ещё и часть пакета порезал. Что самое странное, эти пакеты однотипны и почти идентичны, но почему в одном из пакетов прога решила перевести символы, а вероятность возникновения такой белеберды непредсказуема, может вообще не быть, а может почти все строки так заполнятся, при том, что в текстовом поле всё корректно отображается.

Comment: скорее всего у вас отличаются кодировки (программа отображает в одной кодировке, а в файл пишет в другой). Рекомендую узнать кодировку входящих сообщений. Конвертировать их при получении в UTF8, и работать уже с UTF8 и в программе и в файле.

Comment: Сообщения скорее всего идут в ASCII, а разве они не совместимы? И может ли быть так, что трабл с кодирорвкой возникает словно рандомно и редко?

Comment: Конвертировал, ничего не поменялось

Comment: Рандомно, наврядли. Покажите код, в котором производите конвертирование.

Comment: `MSG = new String(xBeePacket.toString().getBytes(), "UTF-8");` - первая попытка
`String MSG = new String(Controller.MSG.getBytes(),"UTF-8");` - вторая попытка

Comment: попробуйте использовать `getBytes(charsetName)`. Вы узнали исходную кодировку, в которой приходят данные?